# Find the initial velocity which results in a solution which displays simple harmonic motion.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

I've been working on a multi-step problem. Step one involved solving the initial value problem:

Consider the frictionless rod. The equation of motion becomes
$$mr’’-mw^2r=-mg\sin(\omega t)$$
With $g=9.81m/s^2$ and a constant angular speed $\omega$.
The rod is initially horizontal, and the initially horizontal, and the initial conditions for the bead are $r(0)=r_0$ and $r’(0)=v_0$.

I solved this problem. The answer was
$$r(t)=\frac{2wv_0-9.81+2r_0}{4\omega^2}(e^{\omega t})+\left(r_0-\frac{2\omega v_0-9.81+2r_0}{4 \omega^2}\right)(e^{-\omega t})+\frac{9.81}{2\omega^2}\sin(\omega t)$$
[answer to step A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWqHU.png)

Step B involves finding $v_0$.

Consider the initial position to be zero, i.e. $r_0=0$. Find the initial velocity, $v_0$, that results in a solution, r(t), which displays simple harmonic motion, i.e. a solution that does not tend toward infinity.

I've tried solving for $v_0$ by substituting every $r_0$ with $0$, and by taking the derivative of the solution and then substituting every $r_0$ with $0$. All I find is that $0=0$, or $v_0=v_0$.

Through experimenting with a graphing calculator, I've found that $v_0=\frac{g}{2\omega}$.

How can I find the answer through the differential equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\omega>0$ then the coefficient of $e^{\omega t}$ must be zero.
$$\frac{2\omega v_0-g +2r_0}{4\omega ^2}=0$$
Plug in $r_0=0$ and mutiply the above equation by $4\omega^2$:
$$2\omega v_0-g=0\\v_0=\frac{g}{2\omega}$$
Plugging in all back into your $r(t)$, the first two terms are zero, so $$r(t)=\frac{g}{2\omega^2}\sin(\omega t)$$

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. How does $ω>0$ prove that the coefficient of $e^{ωt}$ is equal to zero. When I test it with $w=1$, I can't find that it equals zero.

Comment: The coefficient of $e^{\omega t}$ is a constant (no time dependence). If it is not zero then using  $$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{\omega t}=\infty$$ you will get the first term will go to $\pm\infty$, depending on the sign of the constant. The second term will go to $0$, since $$\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{-\omega t}=0$$and the last term will oscillate. So the first term will be dominant.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Thank you for your help!